# are these two statements equivalent in a circular linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

New to circular linked list, I'm wondering whether these do the same thing as in Goodrich textbook shows the bottom but I 'feel' the top does the exact same thing.

```
tail = new Node(s, tail);
//----------------------------------------------------
tail = new Node(s, null);
tail.setNext(tail);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not the same, because the value of `tail` in the first version is the old value, while the value of `tail` in the second version is the new value, i.e. the new `Node` itself.

That code really only makes sense if the list is empty at the time that code runs, otherwise you wouldn't want the new node to refer to itself as `next`. In that case, the old value of `tail` is null, which means the first version is the same as:

```
tail = new Node(s, null);
```

That makes it very obvious that the two versions are not the same.